# Как задействовать нажатие Enter при использовании поля формы поиска

Tags: javascript, jquery

В поле поиска нужно передать значение и после этого задействовать нажатие Enter для отправки. Я пробовал через submit, через click, но это вероятно это не то.

```
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
var brand = searchParams.get("brand");
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    jQuery('#quickSearchInput').val(brand);
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('#quickSearchInput').submit();
    },2000);
});
```

Comment: Что за поле? Это отправка формы?

Comment: Поле поиска. Оно на сайте вообще срабатывает, когда в нём изменяется сообщение или если в нём нажать Enter. Там рядом никакой кнопки.

Comment: А что у вас по enter происходит? Может лучше сразу выполнить тот функционал, а не имитировать нажатие?

Comment: `jQuery('#quickSearchInput').change()` так попробуйте.. и не понятно зачем тут setTimeout?